# Angular add attribute(directive) before directive compiled

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, components, custom-component

In our project we are developing separate UI Components on angular using custom directives and their attributes like API.

And we faced a problem when element from our component need to be modified with another directive, but this element could be in any tree level.

For instance my component `myFineList`:

```
<li>
  <p>Head element</p>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span>I WANT TO MODIFY THIS ELEMENT</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Using it in the project:

```
 <div>
   <div>Some functionality</div>
   <my-fine-list api-attributes="someValues"></my-fine-list>
 </div>
```

In project I have `drag` directive and I want to add it to `span` element within `myFineList` component.

- I cannot change UI Component (in order to understand "why I cannot?", imagine that this is `input[type="range"]` and I want to add custom directive as attribute to runner to force it to do some stuff for me).
- And not only add `drag` attribute, but it needs to be compiled as directive.

In other words:
How can I add additional custom directive as attribute to element within another custom directive before it is compiled?

Comment: you could use pre link function of directive..

Comment: I need dynamically detect place to put additional directive(attribute) on the most parent directive `myFineList` via API, for instance having something like this `[{to: 'li > span', name: 'drag'}, ...]`